# Should adding a new item to a list<> update previous items in the list?

Tags: c#

I have a list of `StockMultibuy` items, and am building a list of those items. Some of the items in the list I want to have different properties than existing items, and so I tried to create a new instance of the item, changed the property that I wanted, and then added it to the list. I wasn't expecting this to update items that were already in the list. Is this expected behaviour? Is there anything I can do to overcome this?

Thanks

```
StockMultibuy aNewItem = StaticLists.GetStockMultibuyForBarcode(sBarcode);

// If we've got enough items to qualify, then add a free item
if (Reward.StockItemsTaken.Count % (Reward.FreeWhenQualified + Reward.QualifyingQty)
    == Reward.QualifyingQty)
{
    aNewItem.PromoPrice = 0;
}
// Save this for later so that we know we've added a regular item
else
{
    aNewItem.PromoPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(aNewItem.Sell);
}

Reward.StockItemsTaken.Add(aNewItem);
```

Comment: please understand the concept of _references_.

Comment: If you have the same item in the list already it will still add the new item and won't modify anything. The only reason it will modify is if you tell it too somewhere.

Comment: Please show `StaticLists.GetStockMultibuyForBarcode(sBarcode)` method code

Answer (score 6):

You're not adding several different items to the list, you're adding the same exact item several times and modifying it each time.

Classes in C# are reference types; that means each variable doesn't hold the data for the object itself, it just hold onto a reference to where that object is.  Assigning an object to another variable doesn't create a new object, it just copies the reference to that same object.

The issue is that you should be creating a new object (i.e. using the `new` keyword) each time you go to add a new item to the list.

From the looks of your code it would seem that `StaticLists.GetStockMultibuyForBarcode(sBarcode)` isn't returning a new item each time; it's just returning the same item, or at the very least one of the existing items.  You should be creating a new item, copying some of the values of that item over (if that's your intention) and then adding that new item to the list.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected, it will update because it is a reference. I would just make a copy of the object or clone it if you can.